# Get a sum of comple Json structure with linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a complex json structure (at least for me ) that looks like

```
{
"Assets": [{
        "Name": "asset1",
        "Code": "SS-15",
        "Items": [{
                "Name": "Item1",
                "KGs": 255,
                "Cartons": 1222,
                "Containers": 3
            }, {
                "Name": "Item2",
                "KGs": 150,
                "Cartons": 2322,
                "Containers": 5
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "Name": "asset2",
        "Code": "SA-23",
        "Items": [{
                "Name": "Item1",
                "KGs": 88,
                "Cartons": 40,
                "Containers": 1
            }, {
                "Name": "Item2",
                "KGs": 960,
                "Cartons": 710,
                "Containers": 31
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I need to summarize globally how many KGs, Cartons and Containers are for each type of item, something like this:

```
[{
    "unit": "KGs",
    "Item1": 343,
    "Item2": 1110

}, {
    "unit": "Cartons",
    "Item1": 1262,
    "Item2": 3032
}, {
    "unit": "Containers",
    "Item1": 4,
    "Item2": 36
}]
```

I have been using LINQ and so far I have something like:

```
object.SelectMany(x => x.Items.GroupBy(k => k.Name, m => m.KGs)).GroupBy(g => g.Key);
```

It kind of looks what I am looking for but is not giving me the info I need.

Note: I am deserializing the json to a class in my project.

Comment: If it isn't the info you needed, what is it giving you? Also, I wouldn't `GroupBy` inside your `SelectMany`, since you `GroupBy` again afterwards.

Comment: It is giving me a list of grouping <String, myModel>

Comment: @Yatiac Will you always have Item1 and Item2 or possibly others as well?

Comment: @CodingYoshi possibly others as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're going to laugh at this or what because it's so far away from what you where expecting, but the main problem I see in this code is that you're trying to transpose items in a collection (Item1, Item2) to properties in an object ("Item1": 4, "Item2": 36), that forces me to think about dynamic creation of objects by using ExpandoObject class:

(You have to install and import [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) in order to use DistinctBy)

```
var unitsNames = o["Assets"].SelectMany(a => a["Items"]).DistinctBy(i=>i["Name"]).Select(i=>i["Name"].ToString());
var allUnits=o["Assets"].SelectMany(a=>a["Items"]);

var kgs=GetExpandoObject(unitsNames, allUnits,"KGs");
var cartons = GetExpandoObject(unitsNames, allUnits, "Cartons");
var containers = GetExpandoObject(unitsNames, allUnits, "Containers");

List<ExpandoObject> res = new List<ExpandoObject>() 
 { 
  kgs as ExpandoObject,cartons as ExpandoObject,containers as ExpandoObject
 };


string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```

...

```
    private static IDictionary<string, object> GetExpandoObject(IEnumerable<string> unitsNames, IEnumerable<JToken> allUnits, string concept)
    {
        var eo = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        eo.Add("unit", concept);

        foreach (var u in unitsNames)
        {
            var sum = allUnits.Where(un => un["Name"].ToString() == u).Sum(_ => (int)_[concept]);
            eo.Add(u, sum);
        }

        return eo;
    }
```

This is the result:

```
[
 {"unit":"KGs","Item1":343,"Item2":1110},
 {"unit":"Cartons","Item1":1262,"Item2":3032},
 {"unit":"Containers","Item1":4,"Item2":36}
]
```

I'm not saying this is not possible to do with a single Linq query, but I didn't see it that clear, perhaps someone smarter and/or with more available time might achieve it